can $\max(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ be a constraint in Linear Programming?
Let $x_1, x_2, x_3$ be variables. I was wondering whether the constraint $\max(x_1,x_2,x_3)>0$ could be used in a LP when $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are unbounded variables which can be either positive or negative. I feel that it can't as when I graph it with $2$ variables, I didn't see how to enclose the shaded region with lines.  The reason why I am asking is because a worksheet on LP's I was doing included a min max objective, leading me to wonder if constraints can also feature max like this.

Can you post the exercise? Otherwise the answer is: It depends ...

I doubt it is possible without integer programming, because the region of 3-dimensional space where $\max(x_1,x_2,x_3) \ge 0$ is not convex (it's all of the space except for one octant), which seems to be a major barrier to modeling it with LP.

It seems that in LP all variables are positive so your constraint is automatically fulfilled and is redundant.

You can, of cause, run the program three times, with $x_i>0$ for each $i\in[3]$.
